# Yii Error in accessing any controller

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I need immediate help in Yii , dotlogicstest.com/crm/ , the site working fine , but when i click on any link it gives me an error that "An Error Was Encountered",

I tried a lot and even reset every thing (Controller , Model , View) but still getting the same error .

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at your log files?

Comment: how can i access the log file using ftp please ?

Comment: i found the application.log under /crm/protected/runtime , but didn't found any error ..(

Comment: http://dotlogicstest.com/crm/index.php/site/contact is working. It seems to be an error when hiding `index.php`. Please include your .htaccess file.

Comment: Bundle of thanks topher , I am very happy , again thanks :)its working wow...